# Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate when handling a simple bool state

Tags: swiftui

I really don't understand where this error comes from. It stays at the 'return Hstack' line. Could anyone help me to overcome this error?

Should I make a subclass of View and insert it into where the current Image view located?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sensitivity: Double = 50
    @State private var imageUrl: URL = URL(string: "http://localhost")!
    @State private var imageDropped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        let dropDelegate = MyDropDelegate(imageUrl: $imageUrl, imageDropped: $imageDropped)
        
        return HStack {
            VStack {
                Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Input Video"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .padding(.top)
                Image(NSImage())
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .frame(width: 400.0, height: 200.0)
                Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Mask Image"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                Image(self.imageDropped ? NSImage(byReferencing: imageUrl) : NSImage())
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
                    .onDrop(of: ["public.file-url"], delegate:dropDelegate)
            }
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Sensitivity")
                    
                Slider(value: $sensitivity, in: 0...100, step:10)
                    .frame(width: 150.0)
                Spacer()
                    
                    
                Button(action: {print (self.sensitivity)} ) {
                    Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Run"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                }
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 20.0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what exactly the problem is, but try this and the error might get better: delete `return`. remove `let dropDelegate = MyDropDelegate(imageUrl: $imageUrl, imageDropped: $imageDropped)`. add `var dropDelegate: MyDropDelegeteReturnType { MyDropDelegate(imageUrl: $imageUrl, imageDropped: $imageDropped) }` below the last @State private var. dont forget to replace `MyDropDelegeteReturnType` with the type of `MyDropDelegate(imageUrl: $imageUrl, imageDropped: $imageDropped)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it often happens in SwiftUI - the error is mis-detected. You've used incorrect `Image` constructor (it should be `Image(nsImage: )`

Here is fixed part. Tested with Xcode 12b3.

```
return HStack {
    VStack {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Input Video"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .padding(.top)
        Image(nsImage: NSImage())      // << here !!
            .padding(.leading)
            .frame(width: 400.0, height: 200.0)
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Mask Image"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        Image(nsImage: self.imageDropped ?                    // << here !!
          NSImage(byReferencing: imageUrl) : NSImage())
            .padding(.bottom)
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
            .onDrop(of: ["public.file-url"], delegate:dropDelegate)
    }
```

*Note: I assume the `MyDropDelegate` is defined correctly.*

Here is which I replicated to use for compiling:

```
class MyDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    init(imageUrl: Binding<URL>, imageDropped: Binding<Bool>) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Asperi! I'll try it later! Those uninformative errors are really annoying btw.